# Fastest way to convert video to frames wihout saving the frames locally

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, pytorch

I want to apply batch prediction on Videos using Pytorch.

The Problem is I am having many videos to process and don't want to save additional frames.
Is there a way I can save 'n frames' in 1FPS and apply deep learning at the same time?

In other words, I am having VIDEODATASET is there any VIDEODATALOADER?

Comment: I am tempted to cast a close for off-topic due to a request for software libraries etc., see [help/on-topic], but can partially understand the need for this question. Despite this, though, have you tried a simple google search, which comes up with [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-dataloader-for-videos/18253/4)?

Comment: Yes but i do not wish to use GPU for this